# Find Average in a list of values

Tags: python, dictionary

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate of  *finding average values of a list* because this list is a value that is assigned to a key.

Had to clear that up for those who didn't get it.

I have a dictionary where every key has a list/multiple of values:

```
'Jimin ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'Jin': ['1', '0'],
```

I want to print out the average of the values for every key e.g:

```
'Jimin ':[0], 'Jin': [0.5],
```

I have already tried:

```
avgDict = {}
for k,v in StudentGrades.items():
    # v is the list of grades for student k
    avgDict[k] = sum(v)/ float(len(v))
```

But I get the error code:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

And I have also tried:

```
for names, scores in class1.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(names, mean(scores))
```

But I get the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Onyeka/Documents/Onyeka/Computer Science/Controlled            `   Assessment/Programming Project/task3.py", line 68, in <module>`
print("{} : {}".format(names, mean(scores)))
File "C:\Python34\lib\statistics.py", line 331, in mean
T, total, count = _sum(data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\statistics.py", line 161, in _sum
for n,d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
File "C:\Python34\lib\statistics.py", line 247, in _exact_ratio
raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__))
TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to define your `avg` function and have it called during the build of your new dictionary with dictionary comprehension, this way:

```
>>> d = {'Jimin': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'Jin': ['1', '0']}
>>> 
>>> def avg(lst):
        return sum(map(float,lst))/len(lst)

>>> {k:avg(v) for k,v in d.items()}
{'Jin': 0.5, 'Jimin': 0.0}
```

EDIT:

What you got there as error message was due to the fact that your items in list values are `string`, so you need to type cast them to `int` before doing arithmetic operation, that's why you see on the this solution: `map(float, lst)`, which is converting every element of the list from `string` to `float`.

EDIT2:

If all you want is to print averages, then the following will do:

```
>>> for k,v in d.items():
        print('{0} : {1}'.format(k,avg(v)))


Jin : 0.5
Jimin : 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = {'Jimin ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'Jin': ['1', '0']}
>>> {k: sum(int(i) for i in v) / float(len(v)) for k, v in x.items()}
{'Jimin ': 0.0, 'Jin': 0.5}
```

But if you need the average in a list:

```
>>> x = {'Jimin ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'Jin': ['1', '0']}
>>> {k: [sum(int(i) for i in v) / float(len(v))] for k, v in x.items()}
{'Jimin ': [0.0], 'Jin': [0.5]}
```

Or, you could directly convert to `float` and then you don't need `float(len(v))`:

```
>>> x = {'Jimin ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'Jin': ['1', '0']}
>>> {k: [sum(float(i) for i in v) / len(v)] for k, v in x.items()}
{'Jimin ': [0.0], 'Jin': [0.5]}
```

Comment: I tried using : {k: [sum(float(i) for i in v) / len(v)] for k, v in x.items()}, but how would I write this? my IDE doesn't allow it. Also, you didn't make it clear how to print the averages with the names.

Comment: `>>>` sign means that I am showing you how would you write it in the console. It is a console prompt. And, I didn't make it clear how to `print` because I assumed you would know the basics which I think is not the case. You could just use `print({k: [sum(float(i) for i in v) / len(v)] for k, v in x.items()})`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first approach does not work is, that you save the grades as a list of string. One way to make your code work would be to convert the strings to numbers before adding them to the dictionary using the `int` function.

So this code

```
        if class1.get(names):
            class1[names].append(scores)
        else:
            class1[names] = list(scores)
```

would become this:

```
        if class1.get(names):
            class1[names].append(int(scores))
        else:
            class1[names] = list(int(scores))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mean() method of the statistics module:

**Code:**

```
from statistics import mean

A = {'Jimin': [1,2,3], 'Jin': [1,2,3]}

for key in A.keys():
    A[key] = mean(A.get(key))
```

**This yields:**

```
A = {'Jimin': 2.0, 'Jin': 2.0}
```

Comment: doesn't work, I get the same error as my second error block